# How to appends words in Lucene PlainTextDictionary

Tags: java, lucene

I am building a suggest API using Lucene 6.5.1.

My idea was to first create a baseline dictionary -
 `org.apache.lucene.search.spell.Dictionary` with a text file using - `org.apache.lucene.search.spell.PlainTextDictionary` but word list in dictionary shouldn't stop there.

I need an end point to add / append new words to this baseline dictionary too e.g. if few words got missed in my initial text file and some user wants to add it , he / she should be able to do that using a service end point by supplying a `List<String>`. There might be countless other reasons to add a word to existing dictionary.

I am not able to find any straight forward way to achieve that using `SpellChecker` class.

Please suggest.

Using SOLR is not an option here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowing `Document` structure was key. I simply copied four private methods from `SpellChecker` class ( `getMin`, `getMax`, `createDocument` & `addGram`)and wrote something like below.

I am not sure if its 100% correct but its adding words and added words are returned in matches.

```
@Override
    public Boolean addWords(Set<String> words) throws IOException{

        synchronized(modifyCurrentIndexLock){

        IndexWriterConfig wConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(new SimpleAnalyzer());
        wConfig.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);

        try(Directory spellIndex = FSDirectory.open(new File(indexLocation).toPath());
            SpellChecker spellchecker = new SpellChecker(spellIndex); 
            IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(spellIndex, wConfig);)
        {
            for(String word:words){
                if(!spellchecker.exist(word)){

                    logger.debug("Word -> "+word +" doesn't exist in dictionary to trying to add to index");
                    Document doc = createDocument(word, getMin(word.length()), getMax(word.length()));
                    writer.addDocument(doc);
                    writer.commit();
                }
            }
            logger.debug("All valid words added to dictionary");
            return true;
        }

        }

    }
```

where ,

`indexLocation` & `modifyCurrentIndexLock` are class instance fields.